# highstock chart tooltip issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

I have a highstock chart to render a stock price and I have an issue when render the tooltip.

The issue is that even I move my mouse across the boundary of the chart, the tooltip still shows up.

For example,

I have a series of stock price from 2015-01-01 to 2015-12-30 rendered on the chart. Then I zoom in from 2015-05-05 to 2015-06-30. Then the x axis of the chart is from 2015-05-05 to 2015-06-30. When I mouse over at the position of 2015-05-05, I can see the value of the stock price for that date and this is as expected. But when I move my mouse a little bit to the right, I can still see the tooltip show the stock price for 2015-05-04.

I can imagine this is an issue related to rounding. But I am not sure how to get rid of this since people may think that the zoom in range is from 2015-05-04 rather than 2015-05-05. To be more specific, how could I make tooltip not show up when the range is out of chart's x axis boundaries?

Any hint or help would be appreciated!

Comment: Could you provide a plunker ?

Comment: @Alexandre what is a plunker?

Comment: It's a tool for sharing piece of code. http://plnkr.co/
But if you don't know maybe you could give us your code in comment

Comment: Demo would be great, if not plunker, then jsfiddle (just like any demo from Highcharts).